# trying to filter dataGridView from a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, filter, combobox

I’ve done access development several years ago. I am now learning C# and Visual Studio 2013.
I’ve been looking and trying several different solutions that I find here but nothing seems to be working that I find and try in my own code.

I have an Access Database that I’ve converted to SQL. I have built a form with a dataset I’ve built from the new SQL database.

The situation I am dealing with is to take an employee and list all the training said employee has completed.

I have a combo box that allows me to scroll through the list of employees (600+) and choose an employee. This in turn fills in the form with that employee’s information, name, department, hire date, etc.

I have built a dataGridView and the associated dataView. However, the dataGridView shows everyone’s training. I am attempting to filter the data to show only the employee’s classes that were picked in the combo box. I thought I could pull from the employee number in the text box on the form to run a filter on the dataGridView to only show the chosen employee’s classes.

So I thought I could use the code in the text box to launch the filter for the dataGridView. So I wanted to use the Text Change as the trigger to launch the filter. Here is my code:

```
private void eMPLNOTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
       string.Format(“[EMPLNO] = ‘{0}’”, Form1.eMPLNOTextBox.text);
}
```

EMPLNO is the field in the dataset I want to filter. The information for the filter is in the eMPLNOTextbox. This should set the filter for the dataGridView1 and return all the classes based on the EMPLNO. However I am getting an error on Form1.eMLNOTextBox 
:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ‘TRISEnterprise.Form1.eMPLNOTextBox’

Obviously I need to build a reference somewhere. I’m not sure what to reference or where to reference it.

The other item that has me concerned is the fact that it is talking about non-static field. Perhaps I’ve got my code in the wrong place. Perhaps I should pull from the combobox?

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Any suggestions? Again I am new to the C# world and I am learning so if you could please add some comments as to what and where your suggestions should take place would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the combobox to create the filter, it is a very common thing to do. But with 600+ entries it may be better as a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form1` is not an instance of your form, it is a class definition. Use:

```
this.eMPLNOTextBox.Text
```

or simply

```
eMPLNOTextBox.Text
```

> Update

This is tested working:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Foo");
        DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
        row1["Foo"] = "BAR";
        DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
        row2["Foo"] = "BAZZ";

        dt.Rows.Add(row1);
        dt.Rows.Add(row2);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[Foo] = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! It fixed the error in my code, so that is a good thing. However, the code didn’t filter the datagridview which is not such a good thing. So I moved the code to the combobox and got a new error. 

I agree the text box may be a better way to sort through the employees. Then when the employee is selected, the form and the DataGridView update to reflect the choice. Any suggestions on how to filter the datagridview data to find the selected employee number?

Comment: I can't see a reason why that wouldn't work except for the quotes not being the correct characters. Is that a copy/paste thing or is your filter literally using those quote characters?